# Recognizing multiple objects in an image with convolutional neural networks

Tags: image-processing, conv-neural-network

I've seen quite a few CNN code examples for ID'ing images, but they generally relate to a 1-to-1 input to target relationship (like the MNISt handwritten numerals set), and most seem to use similar image dimensions (pixels) for the input image and training images.

So...what is the usual approach for identifying multiple objects in one image?  (like several people, or any other relatively complex scene).  I've seen it done often enough, but haven't seen design approaches mentioned.  Does this require some type of preprocessing or can this be handled directly by a CNN?

Answer (score 3):

I would say the most known family of techniques to retrieve multiple objects from an images would be the *Detection* family.

With *Detection*, the basic idea is to have one or more *Proposal* windows of different sizes and ratios within an image, generated with either a calculated or random array of algorithms.

For each *Proposal* window, the *Classification* algorithm is then executed to reveal what that specific area of the image represents.

The next step would usually be to run a *Merge* process to combine all neighbouring areas into one single classification output.

Note: A *None* class is often also used to represent an area with no specific class found.

Comment: The **Merge** process can instead be a reverse-to-the-pixel function, such that each Proposal window marks the related pixels as *probable* candidates for that classification then after all the Proposal windows mark the related pixels some function like **max** is applied to each pixel classification.  This can create contoured outlines of classified objects and not just boxes.

Comment: Great!  As often happens, a couple keywords were valuable for bootstrapping web searches.  For the benefit of anyone else searching: One good keyword is "R-CNN", with variants by Facebook's Ross Gershick and others, including "Fast R-CNN" and "Faster R-CNN."  It appears that the early approaches relied on multiple passes, and that significant effort has gone into coalescing into a single process.  (I'll need to research that further).

Comment: @wontonimo: Do you know of examples where contoured outlines are used?  Everything I've seen so far uses bounding boxes.

Comment: @Hugh sure, a google image search of "convnet contouring objects" will get that for you.  https://graphics.ethz.ch/~perazzif/masktrack/index.html

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks all.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Now if I can find some Tensorflow code, I'll be on track.